# USB dance pad stopped working

Tags: usb, hardware-failure

I am trying to get a USB dance pad (that was working fine until today or yesterday) to work. It gives me a "device descriptor request failed" error:

[image: error that I get]

**The wiring looked a little frayed, so I decided to open it up. Here is how the inside looks:**

[image: Circuit Board]

[image: Circuit Board 2]

[image: Wire]

At some point the exposed part of the green wire and the (hard) wire going to the capacitor were touching.

I originally thought it was a connection issue. Could it be a firmware corruption issue?

If it is a firmware issue, is there a way to fix it? (e.g. flashing new firmware)

Is it likely that it is an unrepairable hardware issue?

Is there anything I can do to make it work?
(the dance pad was not cheap)

It is worth noting that my computer was runnning a little slower when it was plugged in...

Comment: If it is off topic here, is there a way to migrate the question to [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: This sort of thing tends to be caused by a bad USB connection.

Comment: Aye. Probably hardware failure. Either broken or bad contact. Nothing we can do about that except recommending to test it with a different cable/port. And that assumes that you can replace or unplug the cable. Not a good fit for here,

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to say it, but I would expect this to be a hardware problem, although I am intrigued as to what would cause your computer to run slower...

There would be absolutely no harm in flashing new firmware or re-flashing the original firmware - as long as it is the correct firmware, can you find a reliable source?

If you want to try a few simple fixes, I would suggest reinstalling the drivers for the product, as it may genuinely be an actual driver fault, and not hardware.

Failing that, see if you can contain the wires and prevent any short circuiting - not that I can necessarily see any, but loose wires can sometimes be the cause of a problem.

Do I ask if there's anything else I can offer, sorry to see you're experiencing this problem at all.